# Lazy Load on MULTIPLE horizontal containers

Tags: load, containers, lazy-evaluation

I'm using Lazy Load jQuery plugin:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

My question is:

is it possible to have multiple scrolling containers each with a lazyload images inside, like this:

```
$("#container1 img.lazy").lazyload({ 
container: $("#container1")});

$("#container2 img.lazy").lazyload({ 
container: $("#container2")});
```

When I do this it seems to only keep track of the most recently called.

I tried to call the function two times (one for each container) but it didn't work, I also tried to call both containers this way: container: $("#container1, #container2")}); and didn't work either.

I actually tried a lot of things, but I can't make this works.

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: Please see my question where I found a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376016/multiple-containers-in-lazy-load