# Multiple containers in Lazy Load

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, containers, lazy-loading

I am trying to apply [Lazy Load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) to multiple containers. I found this similar question: [Lazy Load on MULTIPLE horizontal containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539557/lazy-load-on-multiple-horizontal-containers).

this is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/BAFMC/

```
$(".p_outer_content").each(function() {
    var tthis = $(this);
    $(this).find('img').lazyload({
        container: tthis
    });
});​
```

But I have the same problem as the question mentioned, which is that Lazy load only applies to the last container (.p_outer_content) (which is the third one in the fiddle).

Does anyone know how to solve this or has other suggestion?
Thanks in advance'

**EDIT:**

Ok, I tried to reapply the lazyload function each time one of the containers is scrolled:

```
$(".p_outer_content").each(function() {
    var tthis = $(this);
    $(this).find('img').lazyload({
        container: tthis
    });
});

$(".p_outer_content").scroll(function() {
    var tthis = $(this);
    $(this).find('img').lazyload({
        container: tthis
    });

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BAFMC/4/

Which works, but I don't know if it a good way of solving it. Does anyone however come up with a better solution? Thanks'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in the LazyLoad plugin. When you provide a custom container, there was a global variable leak. I have added the minimum necessary fix in this fork here.

https://raw.github.com/marchingants/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.js

Here's a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/BAFMC/5/

I am using the github raw file directly in that example, but in your project, clone the file, minify it and use it locally.

Comment: In the js fiddle, all the images seem to stay grey. Is the code still valid?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get multiple divs to work with lazyload, you have to mention the container id's of the images explicitely. When you have two divs `#container1` and `#container2` then write:

`$("#container1 img.lazy").lazyload({
     container: $("#container1")
});`

`$("#container2 img.lazy").lazyload({
     container: $("#container2")
});`

Instead of: 
`$("img.lazy").lazyload({
     container: $("#container1")
});`

`$("img.lazy").lazyload({
     container: $("#container2")
});`